# How are DNS queries formed from URLs?

Tags: url, dns

Simply put, I'd like a low-level explanation of how an application like a web browser will parse a URL, query a DNS server, and then actually establish a TCP connection.

My example is this:

```
http://site.example.com:7902/svn
```

Now in this situation, with a normal host record, wouldn't the DNS query simply try to resolve the `site.example.com` part into an IP address?

How does the alternate port number factor into the situation? I'd think that the port number is irrelevant for basic DNS resolution. As I'd expect the DNS to resolve `site.example.com` and then to use the port number when forming the TCP packets. I'd then expect the directory `/svn` to simply be passed along once a TCP connection is established.

---

Now for my motivation:

Recently I asked a question about why I would be able to access an Apache server using it's external IP address and alternate port number, but have a problem when using the domain name.

So, my problem was that this worked fine:

```
http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:7902/svn   // this works fine with my external IP
```

...but it failed when using the DNS:

```
http://site.example.com:7902/svn  // this didn't resolve
```

With this problem I used a different DNS provider (instead of dyndns) and everything worked fine. So I asked this question because I am curious why I couldn't use the alternate port number with my dyndns hostname.

Thanks for trying to make sense of this...

Comment: It seems to be explained pretty well here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Structure

Answer (score 1):

Your basic understanding is correct, mostly.  One (often critical) step in this process that you've left out is the presence of the host header.  Basically, the browser will include a request header that looks like this:

```
Host: site.example.com
```

... as part of the request. The web server will use that to figure out how to map the request back to a given site.  This is only necessary when there is more than one site bound to a given IP address, but that is often the case.  The reason you might have had different results when you requested with the IP vs the name could have to do with the presence of this host header, and how the web server is configured to respond to it.

One other thing to keep in mind is differences in routing - if your name is resolving to an IP other than what you are typing manually, that (of course) could lead to different results.  I only mention this because sometimes DNS servers will hand out different IPs based various criteria, such as your location on the network.

Lastly, there is also the possible complexity introduced by proxies.  All bets are off when there is a proxy involved, since that could completely change how the request is processed.

Answer (score 0):

DNS resolves the IP address, period (well... there are different types of DNS entries like A records, CNAME records, MX records, but they don't seem relevant to your question).

The ports are not part of DNS resolution, but an aspect of the server behind the IP address.

Try resolving site.example.com from the command line and see if you get the expected IP address.  For Windows and Unix, you can use

> nslookup site.example.com

Under Windows, if you run `nslookup` without any parameters, you enter nslookup's command mode, where you can then type in

> server 8.8.8.8

where '8.8.8.8' is the DNS server you want to use for resolution (8.8.8.8 is a valid DNS server run by Google, but you can sub any DNS server you want).

You can then just type

> site.example.com

and see how the IP resolves.  Try different DNS servers and see if you get the same IP or not.

Note that it can take a while for DNS changes to propagate.  If the IP address changes, it can take up to a few days for every DNS server in the world to get notice of the change (though in practice these days, a few hours is enough for most of the world to get the update).  Perhaps the IP address changed recently and dyndns did not get the update yet?